# What is this strange canvas behaviour

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html2canvas, canvg

I'm currently trying to create a "screenshot" of a  on a website. 
For this purpose I use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). The problem is that with html2canvas svg images are not rendered in the resulting canvas. As a work around I'm currently trying to use [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) to create a canvas from the svg before creating the screenshot.

Now I face the problem, that the canvas is not created in the full width and height but grows on mousemove, even if there is no mousemove listener or what-so-ever present.

My question is how can I get a canvas with the size of the original svg without any growing?

The problem should be reproducable in this snipped:

```js
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($('svg').get(0)));

$('svg').fadeOut();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<svg id="edgesSVG" class="edgeLayer" style="overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; pointer-events: none;"><defs style="box-sizing: border-box;"><line x1="382.515625" x2="74.90625" y1="333.234375" y2="67.90625" id="029ed6b6-35b7-c6cc-cb6d-6b0877616f15-line" style="stroke-linecap: round; box-sizing: border-box;"></line></defs><g id="029ed6b6-35b7-c6cc-cb6d-6b0877616f15-linegroup" tabindex="0" class="edge" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; stroke-width: 8px; pointer-events: auto;"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#029ed6b6-35b7-c6cc-cb6d-6b0877616f15-line" class="outer" style="box-sizing: border-box; stroke: black;"></use><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#029ed6b6-35b7-c6cc-cb6d-6b0877616f15-line" class="inner" style="box-sizing: border-box; stroke: red; stroke-width: 4px;"></use></g></svg>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I added a proper question to my post. Besides that I  would like to know what's the origin of that growing on mousemove